# Oracle warehouse builder (owb) evaluate stored procedure results in process flow

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, oracle-warehouse-builder

I have a process flow built by someone prior which calls a very simple stored procedure.  upon completion of the procedure the process flow has 2 transitions, one if the stored procedure was successful and the other if not.  However, the stored procedure itself does not return anything that can be directly evaluated by the process flow like a return result.  Now this procedure if it fails (with the ubiquitious max extants problem) it will call the branch which will call a stored procedure for sending a failure email message.  If it succeeds the contrary will occur.

I had to tweak the procedure so I created a new one.  now if it fails or succeeds the success branch is called regardless.  I have checked all the docs from oracle as to how to make this work and for the life of me cannot determine how to make it work correctly.  I first posted this on the oracle forum and got no responses.  Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Comment: Does the existing procedure throw an unhandled exception when it encounters an error?  Does the new procedure?  And why on earth would anyone in 2013 get a max extents exception??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Oracle Warehouse Builder guide:

> When you add a transition to the canvas, by default, the transition has no condition applied to it.

Make sure that you have correctly defined a conditional transition as described in the [Defining Transition Conditions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/owb.112/e10935/design_processflows.htm#WBETL08008) section of the documentation.

A User Defined Activity will return an `ERROR` outcome if:

1. it raises an exception, or
2. it returns the value `3` and the `Use Return as Status` option is set to true

Comment: I altered the stored procedure to have a single out integer return value.  However whether it is set as 1,2, or 3 which are defined as the evaluated values of success, warning, or error it all still branches to the success branch.

Comment: @sldahlin: it needs to be a function, not a procedure

Comment: using stored functions I was able to accomplish what was needed.  the docs need to clarify this in a more complete way though.  thank you most kindly

Answer (score 0):

> "However, the stored procedure itself does not return anything that
>   can be directly evaluated by the process flow like a return result."

This is the crux: if the operating procedure procedure produces no signal how can you tell whether it was successful?  Indeed, what is the definition of success under this circumstance?

I don't understand why, when you had to "tweak the procedure", you wrote a new one instead of, er, tweaking the original procedure.  The only way you're going to solve this is to get some feedback out of the original procedure.

At this point we run out of details.  The direct option is to edit the original procedure so it passes back result info, probably through OUT parameters or else by introducing some logging capability.  Alternatively, re-write it to raise an exception on failure.  The indirection option is to write some queries to establish what the procedure achieved on a given run, and then figure out whether that constitutes success.

Personally, re-writing the original procedure seems the better option.

---

If this answer doesn't help you then you need to explain more about your scenario.  What your procedure does, how you need to evaluate it, why you can't re-write it.